# Rails, is it possible to change the css depending on the value of an model column?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say i have a table like this:[image]

I want to style the rows of the table dependent on the type `{id1: 'Anamnse', id2: 'Befund', id3: 'Therapie'}`. Manually i would simply add the bootstrap classes
[image]

My question is how can I achieve this automatically with ruby? Here is my code, for the table:

```
 <table id="report" class="table table-striped ">
   <tr>
     <th>Typ</th>
     <th>Beschreibung</th>
     <th>Datum</th>
     <th>     </th>
   </tr>
 <% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %></td>
     <td><%= treatment.content %></td>
     <td><%= treatment.day %></td>
     <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td colspan="5">
       <%=    link_to 'Löschen', [treatment.patient, treatment],
                                  :confirm => 'Sind sie sicher?',
                                  :method => :delete %> 
       <% treatment.paintings.each do |paint| %>                          
         <%= image_tag paint.name.url(:thumb) %>
       <% end %>
     </td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
 </table>
```

For conclusion: The styling has to be dependent on the value of the

```
<td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define mapping, e.g.:

```
category_classes = { "Anamnse" => "success", "Befund" => "warning", "Therapie" => "error" }
```

And use this mapping to assign the class:

```
<% category_classes = { "Anamnse" => "error", "Befund" => "warning", "Therapie" => "success" } %>
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
  <tr class="<%= category_classes[treatment.category.try(:typ)] %>">
```

You could also extract this as a helper method, e.g. in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def category_table_row_class(category_typ)
  { "Anamnse" => "success", "Befund" => "warning", "Therapie" => "error"}[category_typ]
end
```

Or use `category.id` instead:

```
def category_table_row_class(category)
  { 1: "success", 2: "warning", 3: "error"}[category.id]
end
```

And call it like:

```
<tr class="<%= category_table_row_class(treatment.category) %>">
```

BTW, you should use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` for the head and body sections.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use an helper method in this way

```
<td <%= row_classname(:typ) %> ><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %></td>
```

and in your related helper

```
def row_classname(type)
  switch type
    when "somevalue"
      classname = "someclass"
    when "othervalue"
       classname = "otherclass"

   "class=\"#{classname}\"" unless classname.nil?

end
```

or something similar

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to "dynamically change the CSS". That's not how CSS is meant to work. Instead, conditionally add a class to the element, and write some new CSS which targets that class.

Something like this:

```
<tr class="<%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %>">
```

Comment: But the values of the typ are Anamnese,Behandlung,Therapie            and i want that for example Anamnese => class=".success"

Comment: Then write a helper method.

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr class="<%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %>">
```

This will add to `tr` class equal to `typ` value.

Comment: But the values of the typ are Anamnese,Behandlung,Therapie            and i want that for example Anamnese => class=".success"